# Facing issue while using Tor with Curl

Tags: php, curl, proxy, socks

**Facing issue while using Tor with Curl:**

I am having this script :

```
$ch = curl_init();<br>
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://whatismyip.org");<br>
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:9050");<br>
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);<br>
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);<br>
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);<br>
$response = curl_exec($ch);<br>
$errno = curl_error($ch);<br>
print_r($errno);<br>
```

When I am using this then facing this error:

**Can't complete SOCKS5 connection to 0.0.0.0:0. (6)**

And When I am using this script:

```
$proxy = "127.0.0.1";<br>
$port = "9050";<br>
$url = "http://whatismyip.org";<br>
$ch = curl_init();<br>
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);<br>
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);<br>
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7 );<br>
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy.':'.$port );<br>
ob_start();<br>
curl_exec ($ch);<br>
curl_close ($ch);<br>
$result = ob_get_contents();<br>
ob_end_clean();<br>
var_dump($result);<br>
```

facing this issue:

**Tor is not an HTTP Proxy**

**It appears you have configured your web browser to use Tor as an HTTP proxy. This is not correct: Tor is a SOCKS proxy, not an HTTP proxy. Please configure your client accordingly.
See https://www.torproject.org/documentation.html for more information.**

If any one know the solution for this then please assist me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I'm using without incident:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://localhost:9150/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The only visible differences I see are localhost vs loopback, prepended http on the `CURLOPT_PROXY`, and various technical differences (verbose, etc).  I do recommend setting a timeout if you're going to curl any onion sites, since in my experience you'll run into loadblocks that leave the connection hanging.

Also, be sure your proxy is actually on the right port!  Depending on how you're using Tor, the proxy could be on port 9050, 9051, 9150, or 9151.  Use `netstat` or a similar utility (bundled with XAMPP for me) or Process Hacker 2 (Network tab) to see what's on what port.  Tor.exe should be on one of the above ports.  Use that for your proxy.

I know I had some trouble with this in the past.  Good luck!

EDIT: A full test code to play with:

```
<?php
    $url = (isset($_REQUEST['url']) ? $_REQUEST['url'] : "http://msydqstlz2kzerdg.onion/search/");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://localhost:9150/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    print_r($output);
    print_r($curl_error);
?>
```